# What rights am I missing?

Tags: kerberos, filenet-p8, filenet, wse3.0, kerberos-delegation

I'm trying to connect to IBM FileNet from my ASP.Net application using Kerberos. My AppPool is running under LocalSystem account. There is a "Trust computer for delegation" permission at AD. There is impersonation enabled at IIS for application. But I'm still getting

> SecurityException: WSE594: InitializeSecurityContext call failed with
>   the following error message: A specified logon session does not exist.
>   It may already have been terminated.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment, so I have to post an answer instead.

You are not really giving enough information here.
Your error is a WSE error, and may not have anything to do with FileNet.

It may help to answer these questions:

1. Have you already set up [FileNet for Kerberos SSO](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.security.doc/p8psn011.htm) and tested to ensure it works?
2. What version of FileNet are you running? (If you still have access to FEM, you can use it to test Kerberos.
3. Why are you using WSE?  MS cut support (a long time ago) and has replaced it with WCF. I only ask as you might find it easier to implement WCF.

You might want to give [Implementing Kerberos](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/sec_procedures.htm%23sec_procedures__sec_procedures_kerberos) a read.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, i've allready set up SSO and ensured it works by accessing FileNet with FEM using integrated login. I'm using WSE because .Net API is using it. My FileNet version is 5.0